# pandas dataframe row multiindex skip one

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm having trouble skipping (including all of) one subindex while chosing the first and third subindex in my dataframe:

I have a dataframe (test) in the form of:

```
signal                     dat1      dat2      dat3
condition epoch time                               
A         0     -1100  1.001322  2.884899 -0.659933
                -1099  1.081918  3.389470 -0.413069
                -1098  1.168483  3.585312 -0.277902
                -1097  1.237908  3.439242 -0.299783
                -1096  1.263452  2.942262 -0.496889
A         1     -1100  1.001322  2.884899 -0.659933
                -1099  1.081918  3.389470 -0.413069
                -1098  1.168483  3.585312 -0.277902
                -1097  1.237908  3.439242 -0.299783
                -1096  1.263452  2.942262 -0.496889
```

And I want to extract conditions and time-points, so the resulting table looks like:

```
signal                     dat1      dat2      dat3
condition epoch time                               
A         0     -1000  1.001322  2.884899 -0.659933
                 -999  1.081918  3.389470 -0.413069
                 -998  1.168483  3.585312 -0.277902
                 -997  1.237908  3.439242 -0.299783
                 -996  1.263452  2.942262 -0.496889
A         1     -1000  1.001322  2.884899 -0.659933
                 -999  1.081918  3.389470 -0.413069
                 -998  1.168483  3.585312 -0.277902
                 -997  1.237908  3.439242 -0.299783
                 -996  1.263452  2.942262 -0.496889
```

I'm new at pandas, and I have tried various things.

I thought the solution would be:

```
test.loc['A',:,[-1000:-50]]
```

And it actually works if I select time points less than about 50 datapoints apart; for more, however, the first index is ignored, and it returns all values from the first index (which is -1100). It really stranges me out. So it looks like this (very well):

```
In [284]: test.loc['A',:,-1000:-950].head()
Out[284]: 
signal                     dat1      dat2      dat3  
condition epoch time                                 
A         0     -1000  0.776851 -0.591070  0.435884 
                -999   0.908675 -1.042335  0.084967 
                -998   0.942239 -1.583269 -0.266314 
                -997   0.901392 -2.146548 -0.602187 
                -996   0.814778 -2.663253 -0.892899
```

But then this happens:

```
test.loc['A',:,-1000:-900].head()
Out[285]: 
signal                     dat1      dat2      dat3  
condition epoch time                                 
A         0     -1100  1.001322  2.884899 -0.659933  
                -1099  1.081918  3.389470 -0.413069  
                -1098  1.168483  3.585312 -0.277902  
                -1097  1.237908  3.439242 -0.299783  
                -1096  1.263452  2.942262 -0.496889
```

anything I'm doing wrong or are there other easy / intuitive indexing (I tried some .ix, slice(), but none successfully) to select all epochs but limit time?

Comment: btw. this happens on pandas 18.0, with 20 epochs, and time values from -1100 to 6000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by a bug; update past [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/13117) fix or to pandas 0.18.2

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [0, 1], range(-1000, 0)])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4000, 3), columns=['dat1', 'dat2', 'dat3'], index=midx)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

>>> df.loc[idx['A', :, -1000:-950], :].head()
               dat1      dat2      dat3
A 0 -1000  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
    -999   2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
    -998   0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
    -997   0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
    -996   0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

To recreate this issue (possibly a bug). Notice in the second head dataframe how the time starts at -1100 despite the slice starting at -1000:

```
np.random.seed(0) 
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['CS'], range(20), range(-1100, 6000)]) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7100*20, 3), columns=['dat1', 'dat2', 'dat3'], index=midx)

>>> df.loc[idx['CS', :, -1000:-950], :].head()
                dat1      dat2      dat3
CS 0 -1000 -1.306527  1.658131 -0.118164
     -999  -0.680178  0.666383 -0.460720
     -998  -1.334258 -1.346718  0.693773
     -997  -0.159573 -0.133702  1.077744
     -996  -1.126826 -0.730678 -0.384880

>>> df.loc[idx['CS', :, -1000:-50], :].head()
                dat1      dat2      dat3
CS 0 -1100  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  # <<< Index Level 2 should start at -1000
     -1099  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
     -1098  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
     -1097  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
     -1096  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

This is using Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) and Pandas 0.18.0.

Comment: that gives me a SyntaxError at `[-1000:-950]`  (at the colon)

Comment: Error fixed.  No brackets required around `-1000:-950`

Comment: it indeed works on your df for all values but same problem on mine. Is it possible the hierarchical row subindexes (signal -- condition,epoch,time) interfere? I have this table like that, though I'm not even far enough to create it for an example.

Comment: Is your multiindex sorted? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex

Comment: Same thing, works for -1000:950 but starts at 1100 if I go up to -950. 
`test.sort_index(level=1).loc[idx['A',:,-1000:-900]].head()`. I tried without level, with `(level=0)`, `level=1`, and combinations. doesn't change =(

Comment: I believe you need to sort the entire index `df.sort_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109008/discussion-between-tnt-and-alexander).

Comment: Workaround: test.loc[idx['CS',test.index.levels[1], -1000:-50], :]

Comment: `df.loc[idx['CS',df.index.levels[1], -1000:-50], :]` does not work with the data above.

Comment: oh, right. I opened a bug report at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12896

Comment: great.  You just need to provide the line showing that `idx = pd.IndexSlice`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that. I added the import statements now, was that it?

Comment: Your Output line included `df.loc[idx['CS', :, -1000:-950], :].head()`, but you never define `idx`.  You just need `idx = pd.IndexSlice` before you refer to it.